# How to retrieve all documents for a given partition key from a CosmosDB container in Java?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

I have a partition key, and I can insert documents correctly, but I would need to get all documents for a given partition key.
I use com.azure.azure-cosmos lib, version 4.12.0.
I tried `CosmosContainer.readAllItems(PartitionKey partitionKey, Class<T> classType)` with correct partitionKey (the same as used for insertion), and JsonNode as class type, but get no results.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, replace entities and Post with your current Collection and Object

```
public void retrieveAllDocs(CosmosEntities entities, ObjectResponse<Post[]> response) {
        CosmosContainer container = entities.getContainer(Post.class);
        PartitionKey partitionKey = entities.createPartitionKey(new Post());
        Post[] posts = container.readAllItems(partitionKey, Post.class).stream().toArray(Post[]::new);
        response.send(posts);
    }
```